# How to get indices of both lists of different length if there is a unique match between them using python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Today I want to know how to get indices for both lists whenever there is match between them. I came across use of enumerate and zip function.  But they work if two list are of same length. Since my inputs are different I want to get indices of both of the lists.

```
# Simulated Time(msec)  Simulated O/p    Actual Time(msec)   Actual o/p
      0                       12.57            0                  12.55
      50                      12.58            100                12.56
     100                      12.55            200                12.60
     150                      12.59            300                12.45
     200                      12.53            400                12.59
     250                      12.87            500                12.78
     300                      12.50            600                12.57
     350                      12.75            700                12.66
     400                      12.80            800                12.78

   ......                    ......          .....               ......
```

Also My simulated data is in different file and generating data at 50Hz rate different from my actual data. Hence Simulated data is of higher length than actual data. But actual data is present in simulated data. I want to get indices of both the the list. Example Simulated Time(msec) 100 (i=2) is matching with indice(j=1) of actual time. If I get indices of both i and j then I can compare corresponding simulated output and actual output at that particular instant.

Lastly I want to iterate till the end of simulated time.

Please suggest how can I solve this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Can you show your code?

Comment: sim_time,sim_val=sim_t[:,0],sim_value[:,1]   act_time,act_valu=act_ time[:,0],act_value[:,1]   index_match=(i for i ,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(sim_time,act_time)) if a==b)    for i in   index_match: print (sim_val-act_valu)

Comment: sorry for this comment,I am unable to format it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `sim`and `act` contains unique values, here is a way to do that, using the numpy set routine `np.in1d`:

```
sim=np.unique(np.random.randint(0,10,3))*10 #sample
act=np.unique(np.random.randint(0,10,5))*10 #sample

i=np.arange(len(sim))[np.in1d(sim,act)]
j=np.arange(len(act))[np.in1d(act,sim)]


print(sim,act,i,j)
#[40 50 70] [10 30 40 50] [0 1] [2 3]
```

Comment: @ B.M How to find the operation sim(i)-act(j) . It is throwing error